# .htaccess, preserve post data on url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

There are posts for similar issues everywhere but none worked in my case.
I want to preserve the POST data when I rewrite the URL.

In my .htaccess file, I have

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-z0-9]+)$ blog-details.php?blog=$1 [L]
```

When the form on this page is submitted, I get an empty array. How can I preserve the POST data with this url rewrite rule.
Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

[EDIT]
It might be due to the case that php extension is removed from the url. I have these rules at the beginning of my .htaccess file after RewriteEngine On.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

The complete .htaccess file is as below:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-z0-9-]+)$ blog-details.php?blog=$1 [L]
```

I have same issue when I rewrite other urls of such kind as well.
Can someone please suggest a solution in this case. Thanks in advance for your suggestions and comments.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please elaborate more on `How can I preserver the POST data with this url rewrite rule` once? Thank you.

Comment: `$_POST` array is not lost with internal rewrite. You may have some other issue causing a full redirect (change of URL in browser)

Comment: "I have same issue when I rewrite other urls of such kind as well." - Are you referring to POST requests? Please give an example.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to POST requests. For example I get the business information (or user information) through their IDs in the database and when I want to update the information, the data are lost somewhere. I send data through POST method. The .htaccess file has something similar to this. RewriteRule ^user-details/([0-9]+)$ userdetails.php?userid=$1 [L] or RewriteRule ^business-details/([0-9]+)$ business.php?bid=$1 [L]. When I want to display the POST data, the result is a null value array. print_r($_POST) -> Array(). Or var_dump($_POST) -> array(0) { }.

Comment: Thos are internal rewrites, they won't cause POST data to be lost. Do you have any other directives or any other `.htaccess` files? Do you have any canonical redirects?

Comment: @MrWhite, as you said, there might be something else causing external redirects. I'll try to find it out. I don't have other directives and don't use other .htaccess file. No canonical redirects either.
Thanks a lot for your useful suggestions. I'll investigate other factors that causes external redirects. At the moment, I'll send my post data to another page which works fine in this case.

Comment: "...might be something else causing external redirects. I'll try to find it out." - Check the network traffic in the browser dev-tools.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, internal rewrites do not lose POST data. (They do not change the request type.)

> It may be due to the reason that php extension is removed from the url. I have these rules at the top of my .htaccess file.

Yes, possibly. If you are submitting to a URL *with* the `.php` extension then the 302 redirect will cause the browser to issue a GET request following the redirect response and the POST data will be lost. However, the form *should* be submitted to the canonical URL (ie. *without* the file extension), so the redirection to remove `.php` should have nothing to do with it.

If you are unable to modify the URL the form is submitted to then you can include an exception in the rule that *removes* the file extension (although this does somewhat defeat the point of having extensionless URLs to begin with).

You could add a *condition* so that only GET requests are redirected. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.?]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```

This should really be a 301 (permanent) redirect. (It currently defaults to a 302, temporary, redirect.)

Alternatively you change this to a 308 (permanent) redirect that should preserve the request method across the redirect. However, there is no point (and inefficient) redirecting the form submission.

To clarify, you are linking to URLs *without* the `.php` extension throughout your site?

Comment: I tried both (adding a condition that only GET requests are redirected as well as 308) unfortunately I still get null value array.

Comment: @mtmehdi Then it would seem something else is going on. To confirm, are you submitting the forms to the extensionless URL? If you monitor the network traffic, are you seeing any redirects? POST data can't simply be lost, unless something (in PHP) is deliberately erasing the POST data or something is triggering a 301/2/3 external redirect.

Comment: ! Yes, I am submitting  the form to extensionless URL. I was setting the action attribute of the form to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which returns extentionless URL. But now I mostly omit action attribute to post data to the same page. Earlier I had a hosting from SiteGround and there, the POST data were lost when I was set the action attribute of the form to another page but when I set the action attribute of form to the same page, it worked well. The same files worked well on the localhost whether I sent data to the same page or another page. I don't notice anything abnormal now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful suggestions. I'll check if something else is triggering external redirects.